# Which is the best way to run some code on the main thread on Linux from another thread (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, x11

There is one GUI application (host) and one plugin application. I need to run some code from plugin in the main thread of host application. I also have no access to the source code of host application.
On Mac it's possible via performSelectorOnMainThread. On Win we can set a hook and then send a message. But what about Linux?

Long story:

Host application can use plugin by the two ways: directly in the main thread (via click button) and in some processes in another thread. Plugin is the Qt-based application and qApp always have to be created in the main thread (to avoid some problems), but it doesn't happen in the second case. On Win and Mac this issue is already solved through invoking creation code in the main thread (as I've written above). I'm looking for the similar way to do that on Linux.

**Upd.**
Finally I found solution of this problem via host API. Unfortunately there is no strong guarantee, because implementation maybe different for another host (despite documentation). But for main cases it works well.
Question is still actual, btw.

Comment: By "main thread" I suspect you mean the GUI's event-handling thread, which is not necessarily the actual main thread of the application.  The mechanism, if there is one, for presenting code to such a thread for it to run depends on the GUI system in use, and perhaps on other details of the application.  We will need some of those details to make an informed recommendation.

Comment: @John Bollinger "GUI's event-handling thread" -- true. Regarding host application type, we actually don't know any details (might be different and mustn't be taken into account) except that it's the GUI application. Also Linux desktop environment might be different too. I've tried to dig into some xlib methods and mechanisms, but didn't find something useful yet.

Comment: If your application is a black box with no documented API, then there's no way we can recommend anything to you.  But it's not completely opaque: it at least presents some kind of plugin interface.  And if it is designed to support third-party plugins then surely there is some kind of programming guide for those.  You can also get a general idea about it by running `ldd` on the binary to see what shared libraries ir relies on.

Comment: @John Bollinger Sorry for misunderstanding, of course there are some well documented APIs and we can, for example, ask host app about some parameters or about invoke some plugin methods. Unfortunately, there is no way to solve described issue through this API. In other aspects, host app is a black box i.e. we cannot know implementation details etc.